# nginx conflicting server name unclear on syntaxic error

Tags: nginx

The following invocation of server names generates an error and the 3rd level domain is ignored, creating an infinite loop directed to the same "/" page.

```
server_name slf.online www.slf.online mrkt.slf.online api.slf.online artterm.slf.online;
[...]
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrkt.slf.online-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrkt.slf.online-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "artterm.slf.online" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
```

if the final entry is removed

```
server_name slf.online www.slf.online mrkt.slf.online api.slf.online;
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
```

But the traffic is not routed for that 3rd level domain.
I fail to see where the syntax for a valid 3rd level domain is mistaken.

This configuration file for this domain set `sites-enabled/slf` has two `server` blocks, the second of which is generated by letsencrypt to redirect traffic to the https page:

```
if ($host = artterm.slf.online) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

I don't understand how this code can be a possible source of the problem. nor if the second block is at play (why would the absence of the last entry not create an ignore case?)

There is another configuration file that has the same second level domain, but different third level ones

```
server_name prva.sfl.online prve.slf.online sales.slf.online;
```

This is another assumption of culpability, but again I fail to see where the brittleness would come from.

How can the be overcome?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Check the `server` blocks containing a `listen 443` directive for the duplicate `server_name`.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard Smith comment was correct.

`nginx -T`, providing the full configuration stack for nginx, revealed that Lets Encrypt was writing certificate and `server_name` data to a seperate certificate below what I normally expected for that application's configuration (and off screen thus throwing me off).

That naturally led the traffic to another application's logic which did not know what to do with the request and directed it towards an non-self-exiting loop.

*Note: This is not the first time I have observed unexpected, wonky behaviour from automated Let's Encrypt scripts.*